# How to implement an array of bits in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, bitwise-operators, std-bitset

I am trying to write a C++ template class which contains an array of bits (as a member variable). The size of the bit-array is known at compile time, so I'd really like it to be a `std::bitset`, but I'm having difficulty writing an `operator[]` function to **set** the bits.

For example, I'd like my class to start out something like this:

```
template<size_t N>
class bitvector
{
public:
    bool operator[](size_t i) const { return bits[i]; }
    bool& operator[](size_t i) { return bits[i]; }
private:
    std::bitset<N> bits;
};
```

The getter works okay. The problem is that the `std::bitset::operator[]` setter function returns a `std::bitset::reference` (not a `bool&`) which is itself templated. I'm not too experienced with templates, but the following attempt failed:

```
template<size_t K>
std::bitset<K>::reference operator[](size_t i) { return bits[i]; }
```

with the following error `need 'typename' before 'std::bitset<K>::reference' because 'std::bitset<K>' is a dependent scope`. I tried some googling, but to no avail.

Is `std::bitset` a suitable tool for this task? If so, how can I write the setter function? If not, what can I use instead? (I would still like it to be actually stored as bits, and `std::vector<bool>` doesn't seem quite right, as I want the array size to be strictly fixed at compile time).

Comment: I don't understand.  The `std::bitset` [has an `operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_at), so why are you reinventing the wheel?

Comment: it seems the error is self explanatory. add `typename before...`. So why don't you try doing that?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Probably a minimal version of a larger class to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews As pointed out in another comment, I was trying to give a minimal example from what will be a much larger class.

Comment: @NowhereMan Of course, I did try doing that, but it produced a host of new errors that seemed to be leading me off in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just return a `std::bitset<N>::reference` as follows:

```
template<size_t N>
class bitvector
{
public:
    bool operator[](size_t i) const { return bits[i]; }
    typename std::bitset<N>::reference operator[](size_t i) { return bits[i]; }
private:
    std::bitset<N> bits;
};
```

There's no need to have the additional `template<size_t K>` since you can still access the original template parameter N, and under no circumstances would you want the N and your K to be different.

You need the `typename` before the function's return type to tell the compiler the `::reference` is a type rather than a value.

For example:

```
struct Foo{
   typedef int reference;
};

struct Bar{
    static int reference;
};
```

Here `Foo::reference` is a type, but `Bar::reference` is a variable, without the `typename` before the return type the compiler will complain as it could be that `std::bitset<N>::reference` is a variable. (The compiler should have all the information it needs to work out that it isn't a value, but for some reason it is required anyway).

Comment: Great answer. Thank you so much for explaining it so clearly.